# Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'jpegData'

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

[image: Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'jpegData']

Same code is working perfectly in another view controller.Help me Out to get rid of this problem. Here Is the Code....

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SettingTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTexfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Edit Profile"
        fetchCurrentUser()
    }
    func fetchCurrentUser() {
        Api.User.observeCurrentUser { (user) in
            self.usernameTexfield.text = user.username
            self.emailTextfield.text = user.email
            if let profileUrl = URL(string: user.profileImageUrl!) {
                self.profileImgView.sd_setImage(with: profileUrl)
            }
            
        }
    }
    @IBAction func SaveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

        if let profileImg = self.profileImgView, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            AuthService.updateUserInfo(username: usernameTexfield.text!, email: emailTextfield.text!, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: {
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
            }, onError: { (errorMaessage) in
                ProgressHUD.showError(errorMaessage)
            })
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func LogOutButton_TouchUpinside(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func EditProfileBtn_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        let pickercontroller = UIImagePickerController()
        pickercontroller.delegate = self
        present(pickercontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
extension SettingTableViewController {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print("did finish picking media")
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOrignalImage"]
            as? UIImage{
            profileImgView.image =  image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: "Same code is working perfectly in another view controller." No it isn't.

Comment: `.jpegData` is a function on `UIImage` not `UIImageView` so your code should be `if let profileImg = self.profileImgView.image ...`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the `image` property of the `profileImgView` not the `profileImgView` directly.

So Replace this line
    `if let profileImg = self.profileImgView, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {`

with this

`if let profileImg = self.profileImgView.image, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {`

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting **profileImgView** to **profileImg**. You have to set **profileImageView.image** to get this work properly.

Try this code in **Save button action**:

```
@IBAction func SaveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        if let profileImg = self.profileImgView.image, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            AuthService.updateUserInfo(username: usernameTexfield.text!, email: emailTextfield.text!, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: {
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
            }, onError: { (errorMaessage) in
                ProgressHUD.showError(errorMaessage)
            })
        }
    }
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable, let:

> var imageDataURL = ""

Now in the *delegate function* of **imagePickerController** you have to do:

```
extension SettingTableViewController {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print("did finish picking media")
        if let image = info["UIImagePickerControllerOrignalImage"]
            as? UIImage{

        profileImgView.image =  image 
        
        guard let reducedImage = image.jpegData(compressionQuality : 0.0) else {print("image not compressed");return}
        let CompressedImg = reducedImage.base64EncodedString()
        self.imageDataURL = CompressedImg
            
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now in **SaveButton action** do this:

```
@IBAction func SaveButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
 AuthService.updateUserInfo(username: usernameTexfield.text!, email: emailTextfield.text!, imageData: self.imageDataURL, onSuccess: {
                ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Success")
            }, onError: { (errorMaessage) in
                ProgressHUD.showError(errorMaessage)
            })
        }
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

[This Really works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7O04.png)

@M.Ali @TaimoorArif After using Image property The Build Succeed, can you guys check the Edit profile button's code why the image is not uploading. I think there is something that I am missing.

Comment: see my second answer